# How to use custom attr with selector in Android?

Tags: android, selector

This is my custom attr:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>    
    <declare-styleable name="MyComponent">
        <attr name="mycustom" format="boolean"/>
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

This is how I use it in layout:

```
<com.edu.MyComponent
    style="@style/MyStyle"
    app:mycustom="true"/>
```

It works ok in MyComponent class because I get true from this call:

```
typedArray.getBoolean(R.styleable.MyComponent_mycustom, false);
```

However, it doesn't have any effect in selector:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item app:mycustom="false">
        (...)
    </item>
    <item app:mycustom="true">
        (...)
    </item>
</selector>
```

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:**

The trick was to correctly use refreshDrawableState() + onCreateDrawableState().
As to using custom attribute in selectors additionally for **child** elements I had to also use this:

```
android:duplicateParentState="true"
```

Comment: You need to add your attribute to the `View`'s drawable state. Have a look at Step 3 here: https://charlesharley.com/2012/programming/custom-drawable-states-in-android.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Step 3 in the mentioned tutorial is quite confusing because in github code the most important function -> refreshDrawableState() is indirectly called (by setMessageUnread) from completely different class (HomeActivity) which was not even mentioned in the tutorial.

Comment: Ah, gotcha. I must admit, it's been many years since I've used or read that. I just recall that it was a really straightforward example with no clutter, which is why I keep it as an example link. Anyhoo, glad you got it figured out. Cheers!